# Camera stopped working after updating to WP 8.1 GDR 1 DP

Tags: nokia-lumia-920, camera, 8.1-update-1

My Camera does not launch after updates to WP 8.1 GDR 1(Update 1)

Things i tried :
1) Used all three apps[Nokia Camera, Nokia Camera Beta and Microsoft Camera]
2) Soft reset
3) Reset camera in settings.

I tried to look around for a fix everywhere, but not a single person seems to have found what the problem is.

There is a huge thread on this subject [here](http://forums.wpcentral.com/update-1-windows-phone-8-1-gdr1/301117-lumia-1020-camera-does-not-work-after-update.html)

Anyone with similar problem and managed to fix it. Please let me know the fix.

I have a 920 AT&T

Comment: Were you able to fix this issue?

Comment: Nope :( Hard reset is ruled out for me for now due to some reasons. Still looking out for more solutions

Comment: Samsung is currently releasing the regular WP8.1 GDR 1 Update. Check if you can install that one and if that fixes your problem. Btw. why can't you do a hard reset? WP8.1 brought more backup options which make it less painful.

Comment: Try restarting your phone. Clearing the temp files, and then restarting again.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/8632/106

Answer (score 1):

Issues resulting from an update to WP8.1 usually can be fixed by doing a hard reset.
Just make sure to use the new backup features, this will save you a lot of time when setting up your phone again.

Comment: Many have said that Hard reset does not fix the problem. :(

Comment: only one way to find out. You might have to do it without the backup restore, in case wrong settings are being backed up. I'd simply try first with the restore and if that does not work, again without. I know it's a pain.

Comment: Someone did say that, the camera worked without the backup. Also what do i lose when i hard reset and restore from backup?

Comment: you do lose all your documents, photos, music, texts and all the app data for apps that don't make backups in the cloud. Basically everything that doens't get synced through your Microsoft Account.

Answer (score 0):

I had a camera issue with my Nokia Lumia 1020, after a firmware update to 8.1, I attempted to change from the Lumia camera app to the Microsoft one, at that point the camera quit working, even when I tried to switching back to the Lumia app, I then reset the camera, did a soft reboot, then did a hard reboot, then reinstalled the latest 8.1 firmware from my computer, nothing worked....until I let the battery run all the way down till then phone displayed the goodbye msg and then shutdown, I then recharged the phone & amazingly the camera's now working just fine, even when I switch between the 2 camera apps!!!....

Comment: wow this is a strange fix. Let me see.