# What might be causing my camera to misbehave?

Tags: 8.1, camera, nokia-lumia-1020

I chose the Lumia 1020 as a handy standby camera when I haven't got my normal photography kit with me; However since updating to 8.1 (Cyan), and later to 8.1. update 1 (Denim), I've noticed that the camera appears to work up until the point I take a photo, at which point the taken photo remains on the screen, with "saving" and a progress indicator at the top of the screen.

A reboot of the phone sorts this, but I lose the ability for more spontaneous photos, nearly missing [a nice sunset](http://instagram.com/p/xCn7AMtVKh/) a few weeks back. After reboot, the phone is happy to take photos for "a while", but the fault *will* return.

I can see how this *could* be down to going into an app that is fiddling with the camera when it doesn't need to, and leaving it mushed, or a fault within the [Lumia Camera app](http://www.windowsphone.com/s?appId=bfd2d954-12da-415c-ad99-69a20f101e04); but has anyone else seen this problem, and been able to figure out the cause, or even a faster way of getting the phone back into a position for taking photos?

Comment: I'm not sure if this would make any difference, but have you tried reinstalling the app, since Lumia Camera Classic is now the app for phones running anything older than Denim, and Lumia Camera is for Denim?

Comment: Similar to what @Shawn asks, have you tried using the Microsoft Camera app instead of Lumia Camera? Microsoft Camera can't make very good use of the 1020's amazing sensor, but it would at least let you figure out if the problem is with the app or with the phone in some other way.

Answer (score 1):

Usually issues caused by the 8.1 update can be fixed by doing a factory reset.

Comment: I've not seen issues since upgrading to Denim, and doing a hard reset (to fix up the [call+SMS filter](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/8916/106)), so either one of those two seems to have resolved it.

Comment: Actually, I've seen lots of issues since being on Denim, primarily with the Lumia Camera app.

Comment: I have done a factory resent, with no improvement in the camera