# How can I block calls from withheld numbers?

Tags: 8.1-update-1, call-sms-filter, lumia-denim-update

There used to be the Call + SMS filter that I used to use, but now that the Denim update has been rolled out, it is no longer available, so is there another option for blocking the barrage of automated calls from withheld numbers? Is this something I can ask Cortana to do for me?

Comment: Call+SMS filter is still there in Settings. What phone do you have? What's the OS and firmware version?

Comment: @Indrek Sorry, was just answering self - turns out that whilst the tile remains, they've changed "something" so it thinks it's a completely different app; thought it a useful question for anyone else moving to Denim (even though my phone is convinced it's Cyan)

Answer (score 6):

Whilst the live tile has a big warning icon, and a warning saying the app is no longer available, you can set it up again by going to **settings** > **call+SMS filter** (near the bottom), and set it up again, and no more spam calls or texts