# Nokia Lumia 1020 Camera doesn't work with 8.1 OS

Tags: 8.1, camera, nokia-lumia-1020

Why doesn't the new 8.1 OS software support the 41MP camera in the Lumia 1020?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/8632/106

Comment: Or to put it another way, it does work, just not reliably with the Lumia camera app (the built in camera app is fine though)

Answer (score 0):

Its bluetooth , it always has been nobody's exactly sure why though. To solve just go into settings and turn off Bluetooth. Hope this helps xD

Comment: That isn't it, at least not for my 1020...